# Ag-grid custom tooltip component template not showing

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

With ag-grid and ng7, I created a custom tooltip component, binding it to column definition tooltipComponent, along with headertooltip, and headername. When I hover on the header, the `console.log` from agInit gets called, however the template is not rendered

base on [official ag-grid tooltip guide](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tooltip-component/), there is a method called `getGui` that could also render html. Tried that as well, nothing shown when hover on header.

```
    <ag-grid-angular
      #agGrid
      [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"
      ...
    ></ag-grid-angular>
```

```
    headerName: 'Atheltes`
    tooltipComponent: 'customTooltip',
    headerTooltip: 'Helper text should show here'
    this.frameworkComponents = { customTooltip: CustomTooltipComponent };
```

```
@Component({
    selector: 'ffp-tooltip-component',
    template: `<div>It should show helper text</div>`,
})
export class CustomTooltipComponent implements ITooltipAngularComp {
    agInit(params: ITooltipParams) {
       console.log('this console log works!!')
       // console.log above gets called, however, no template is shown.
    }

    getGui(): any {
    }
}
```

I expect when I hover on the header `Atheletes`, I should see a tooltip text of `Helper text should show here`.

Answer (score 12):

I tried out the Plunker example provided by ag-grid at https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tooltip-component and found a couple of things that may help:

1. While I couldn't find it in the documentation, it seems that the column definition must have a `tooltipField` entry, or the tooltip will not show.
2. There is a significant delay, maybe 3 seconds or so, before the tooltip displays,
   so you need to hover over a cell for at least that long to see the tooltip.

Comment: For second point, if you don't want the delay, set `tooltipShowDelay: 0,` in `gridOptions`

Answer (score -1):

I modified tooltip property of ag-grid and it worked out for me.

```
 .ag-tooltip {
      background-color: white !important;
      border-radius: 1px !important;
      padding: 5px !important;
      border-width: 1px !important;
      border-style: solid !important;
      border-color: #545454 !important;
}
```